# Is there authoritative documentation on how to generate a P2WPKH address?

Tags: address-generation, bech32-address, p2wpkh, documentation

I Googled and found some BIPs but looking through bitcoincore.org, I could not find documentation on the process to generate a P2WPKH address.

Looking through other random articles, I see the process is roughly something like:

1. Start with a compressed public key
2. Perform SHA-256 followed by RIPEMD-160 hashing on it
3. Add a witness version byte
4. Encode using Bech32

Again, these are just random internet articles so not authoritative and may be missing steps and/or important details.

So where can I find something authoritative? If a source doesn't exist, how is one meant to implement the steps required to generate?

Comment: BIP141 and BIP173 should provide a complete specification on how to create and encode P2WPKH outputs. If there isn't a specific problem you're facing, your question might get closed for being too vague.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Thank you. I think I did read one of those but couldn't formulate the complete picture. Maybe the other has the missing info I need. Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, with links to BIPs: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32

Comment: Thanks. I should've mentioned, I did read through that before I posted the question, but wasn't sure on the site's authoritativeness. Any thoughts?